# Set-dynamic Distribution using powershell and CSV

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am running a small powershell code with CSV file:
Code:

```
$Data = Import-Csv "C:\DDL\Set-DDL.csv"
ForEach ($wm in $Data) {
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity $wm.Identity -RecipientFilter {(UserAccountControl -ne "514") -and (Department -like $wm.Dept)}}
```

CSV:

```
Identity,Dept
LearnTest-DDL2,(279) Operational Excellence
LearnTest-DDL3,(280) HPS - Operational Performance
```

It gives error:
Write-ErrorMessage :

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'RecipientFilter'.
> Cannot convert value "(UserAccountControl -ne "514") -and (Department
> -like $wm.Dept)" to type "System.String". Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

And this is particularly gets, for part (Department -like $wm.Dept)

Help me to resolve this

Comment: You have "514" inside double quotes which make it a string.  Try removing the double quotes so value is treated as a number.

Comment: The value you pass to parameter RecipientFilter must be a string. Check example 2 in this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-dynamicdistributiongroup?view=exchange-ps.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I tried with removing double quotes from "514" , but still gives error. As I mentioned in the main issue, it throws error specially for part (Department -like $wm.Dept). It is working well, if I remove it. Error after removing double quotes: Set-DynamicDistributionGroup: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'RecipientFilter'. Cannot convert value "(UserAccountControl -ne 514) -and (Department -like $wm.Dept) -and (Company -eq "EHI")" to type "System.String". Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: How is field defined in azure.  There is an inconsistency in the definition of the type.  CSV is text and it appears that a header in the CSV file is not matching the column name in the database.

Comment: in my CSV file, Identity and Dept are two column headers

Comment: Try `-RecipientFilter "UserAccountControl -ne 514 -and Department -eq '$($wm.Dept)'"`

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to set the Set-dynamic Distribution using Powershell, As I got below result :**

[image]

To resolve this issue, you can modify the recipient filter to check if the `$wm.Department` variable is not null or empty before using it in the filter.

You can use below script.

```
$departmentFilter = ""
if ($wm.Department) {
    $departmentFilter = "(Department -like '$($wm.Department)')"
}
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity $dgIdentity -RecipientFilter "($departmentFilter)"
```

When i ran the above script, it got executed successfully.

[image]

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity $wm.Identity -RecipientFilter $departmentFilter -ManagedBy ITAdmin -MailTip "Distribution List for anyone with Architect in the job title"
```

When i try to add the user to **DynamicDistributionGroup**, it got added successfully.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Refer: [How to Create Exchange Dynamic Distribution Lists with Custom Recipient Filters](https://office365itpros.com/2021/01/18/dynamic-distribution-lists-filters/)